# Cannot find module 'ldapjs'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap

I'm trying to build a LDAP client using NodeJS with the following code:

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var client = ldap.createClient({
    url: 'ldap://10.11.4.130:389',
});
```

But when I try to run, this error appears:

```
module.js:340
     throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'ldapjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/elias/workspace/TestJS/app.js:64:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

The `ldapjs` was installed via `npm` with `npm install ldapjs`

```
[root@localhost ~]# npm ls
/root
├── async@0.9.0
├─┬ express@4.8.6
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.0.7
│ │ ├── mime-types@1.0.2
│ │ └── negotiator@0.4.7
[...] other modules
└─┬ ldapjs@0.7.1         <-----
  ├── asn1@0.2.1
  ├── assert-plus@0.1.5
  ├─┬ bunyan@0.22.1
  │ └── mv@0.0.5
  ├── dtrace-provider@0.2.8
  ├─┬ nopt@2.1.1
  │ └── abbrev@1.0.5
  └─┬ pooling@0.4.6
    ├── once@1.3.0
    └─┬ vasync@1.4.0
      ├─┬ jsprim@0.3.0
      │ ├── extsprintf@1.0.0
      │ ├── json-schema@0.2.2
      │ └── verror@1.3.3
      └─┬ verror@1.1.0
        └── extsprintf@1.0.0
[root@localhost ~]# which node
/bin/node
[root@localhost ~]# which npm
/bin/npm
[root@localhost ~]# node -v
v0.10.30
[root@localhost ~]# npm -v
1.3.6
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Is your script in `/root`?

Comment: No. I installed as root, but the app.js is in `/home/elias`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your script is in `/home/elias/workspace/TestJS`, but you are running `npm ls` from `/root`, so it looks like you installed the modules to the wrong place. Try doing `npm install ldapjs` from `/home/elias/workspace/TestJS`.

Modules are installed locally, typically under a subdirectory of your current working directory (unless there is already a `node_modules` in any parent directories of the cwd).

Answer (score 0):

An npm install ldapjs would work. Also if you are using git, and the npm install ldapjs does not work initially, try a git clean -fdx to remove all installed packages and then do the npm install (if ldapjs was not added to your package.json) then, npm install ldapjs